# Azure Pipeline not being triggered when commit is made in another repo

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have a yaml file for a repo called modules seen below, and also created a pipeline for that repo (for the release/test branch).

When a commit is made to this repo, testrepo1 or testrepo2 this pipeline should trigger. Right now it triggers when I make a commit to the modules repo, but not to testrepo1 or testrepo2. I am making the commit in the release/test branch for all repos.

Why does it not trigger?

```yaml
trigger:
  - release/test

pool:
  name: <REDACTED>
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals  <REDACTED>

# Overrides the value for Build.BuildNumber, which is used to name the artifact (ZIP file) that is produced
name: '$(Date:yyyyMMdd)T$(Hours)$(Minutes)$(Seconds)'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: testrepo1
      type: git
      ref: release/test
      name: <REDACTED>/testrepo1
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - release/test

    - repository: testrepo2
      type: git
      ref: release/test
      name: <REDACTED>/testrepo2
      trigger:
        branches:
          include:
            - release/test

stages:
  - stage: 'BuildAndUploadArtifact'
    jobs:
      - job:
        workspace:
          clean: all
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          # Core repos
          - checkout: testrepo1
          - checkout: testrepo2

         

        <do a bunch of work in tasks>
```

EDIT: This works for the develop branch, but not feature/test:

```yaml
trigger:
  - release/test

pool:
  name: <REDACTED>
  demands:
    - agent.name -equals  <REDACTED>

# Overrides the value for Build.BuildNumber, which is used to name the artifact (ZIP file) that is produced
name: '$(Date:yyyyMMdd)T$(Hours)$(Minutes)$(Seconds)'

resources:
  repositories:
    - repository: testrepo1
      type: git
      ref: develop
      name: <REDACTED>/testrepo1
      trigger:
      - develop

    - repository: testrepo2
      type: git
      ref: develop
      name: <REDACTED>/testrepo2
      trigger:
      - develop

stages:
  - stage: 'BuildAndUploadArtifact'
    jobs:
      - job:
        workspace:
          clean: all
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          # Core repos
          - checkout: testrepo1
          - checkout: testrepo2

         

        <do a bunch of work in tasks>
```

Comment: I removed this part and changed the branch to be develop instead: 

  - repository: testrepo2
      type: git
      ref: develop
      name: <REDACTED>/testrepo2
      trigger:
       -develop

And that seems to work. But when I want to use the release/test branch it doesn't work.

Comment: Don't you need to specify that your trigger is a branch using `branches: include:` (both on separate lines indenting each time). Like you did under the resources section?

Comment: Also, can you add a code example to your question of the changes elude to in your comment?

Comment: Doesn't seem like it. I added a proper example to my original question.

Comment: When you changed to `develop` you also removed `branches: include:`. Does removing this from the original work?

Comment: No it does not. Does it have something to do with the slash in the branch name?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256481/discussion-between-b-griffin-and-rattletrap).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a pipeline is triggered, Azure Pipelines has to determine the version of the YAML file that should be used and a version for each repository that should be checked out. If a change to the `self` repository triggers a pipeline, then the commit that triggered the pipeline is used to determine the version of the YAML file. If a change to any other repository resource triggers the pipeline, then the latest version of YAML from the **default branch** of `self` repository is used. See the detailed info from [Triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/repos/multi-repo-checkout?view=azure-devops#triggers:%7E:text=When%20a%20pipeline,repository%20is%20used.).

When you make changes in `release/test` branch of modules repo, the YAML in `release/test` branch will be used. Therefore, your pipeline can be triggered.

When you commit in testrepo1 or testrepo2, the pipeline will use the YAML in the **default** branch of the modules repo. But at this time, your YAML is in the `release/test` branch, so the pipeline will not be triggered.

To make it work, you can try to change `release/test` as the default branch in modules repo (Not recommended, but you can do it for test). Or you can add the YAML in the default branch of modules repo.

Comment: This is a problem for us. We want to use a Gitflow-like workflow where we have parallel releases. In the example in my post each of the repos (modules, testrepo1, testrepo2) would have multiple release branches:
release/Alpha
release/Beta
/release/Charlie

If a commit is made to the charlie branch of any of the three repos then the pipeline in the charlie branch of modules should trigger. And vice versa. Surely there is a way to make this work? 

Thank you.

Comment: You wrote "To make it work, you can try to change release/test as the default branch in modules repo (Not recommended, but you can do it for test)."

I followed this article and tried to do that: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-default-branch?view=azure-devops

But it didn't seem to do anything. If I could do that for every branch of the modules repo (which each has its own pipeline) then this could work. In that way the default branch would be different for each pipeline. 

Any idea why it isn't working?

Comment: What I mean by "change release/test as the default branch in modules repo" is to [change the default branch of the modules repo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/change-default-branch?view=azure-devops#set-a-new-default-branch) to `release/test`, rather than changing the default branch of the pipeline. This method is only used for testing to prove that the current issue is because your YAML is not in the default branch of the `modules` repo.

Comment: As mentioned in the official doc, if a change to any other repository resource triggers the pipeline, then the latest version of YAML from the **default** branch of **self repository** is used. This is by design. The pipeline's default branch defines the pipeline version used for [pipeline resource triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops) instead of repo resource trigger. Therefore, it doesn't work after changing pipeline's default branch.

Comment: I see what you mean. I tried changing the default branch and that does actually work. Like you wrote, this is a temporary fix and won't work in the long run since we will have multiple parallel releases that have to work at the same time.

This would not be an issue if the YAML file would be the same from release to release. That is not the case, however. From release to release the YAML file can and will look slightly different. This means that when a new release is made we have to create a new YAML file and a new pipeline. 

I feel like this should be supported, but maybe not..

Comment: For future reference I'll add that so far I've found two (bad) workarounds for this issue: 
1. As we start the new release, create a new branch in the modules repo and make that the default branch. If a hotfix needs to be made to the previous release (branch), manually trigger that pipeline.

2. Create a new modules repo for each release and only have one branch there that will always be the default branch.